# Multiple loops within loops on different rows

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I need a loop that calls in a custom post type called 'team members' the slug for which is 'team'. The team members are displayed in rows of five with each member consisting of its own avatar and slide down toggle content in a separate DIV out side the list of avatars. I've written out a basic loop structure which i'm not sure if its best or right way to do it. Can someone help me please?

```
                    /* ROW 1 */

                query_posts('showposts=5');
                $ids = array();

                /* Loop 1 A - displays the row of avatars */
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    $ids[] = get_the_ID();
                    the_title();
                endwhile;

                /* Loop 1 B - displays the slide down content in new row for each avatar above */
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    $ids[] = get_the_ID();
                    the_content();
                endwhile;



                /* ROW 2 */

                //Write code to do second row if number posts greater than 5. 
                //If post greater than 5 do...

                /* Loop 2 A - displays the row of avatars */
                query_posts(array('post__not_in' => $ids, 'showposts=5');

                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    the_title();
                endwhile;

                /* Loop 2 B - displays the slide down content in new row for each avatar above */
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    the_content();
                endwhile;



                /* ROW 3 */

                //Write code to do third row if number posts greater than 15. 
                //If post greater than 10 do...

                /* Loop 3 A - displays the row of avatars */
                $ids_row_two = query_posts(array('post__not_in' => $ids));
                $ids_row_three = query_posts(array('post__not_in' => $ids_row_three));
                query_posts(array('post__not_in' => $ids_row_three, 'showposts=5'));

                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    $ids[] = get_the_ID();
                    the_title();
                endwhile;

                /* Loop 3 B - displays the slide down content in new row for each avatar above */
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    $ids[] = get_the_ID();
                    the_content();
                endwhile;
```

Here is the HTML structure I wish to output...

```
<!-- row 1 -->
                 <!-- Avatars -->
                 <div class="member_block">
                     <div class="container avatars">

                     <!-- avatar 1 --->
                        <div id="show_ryan" class="box five columns" data-target="#member_ryan">
                            <div class="avatar avatar-on-hidden">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/ryan.png">
                                <h4 class="name">Ryan</h4>
                                <p class="position">Creative Director</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="avatar2 avatar-on-hover">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/ryan.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                     <!-- avatar 2 --->

                        <div id="show_brian" class="box five columns" data-target="#member_brian">
                            <div class="avatar avatar-on-hidden">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/brian.png">
                                <h4 class="name">Brian</h4>
                                <p class="position">Director</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="avatar2 avatar-on-hover">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/brian.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                     <!-- avatar 3 --->

                        <div id="show_emma" class="box five columns" data-target="#member_emma">
                            <div class="avatar avatar-on-hidden">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/emma.png">
                                <h4 class="name">Emma</h4>
                                <p class="position">Creative Director</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="avatar2 avatar-on-hover">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/emma.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                     <!-- avatar 4 --->

                        <div id="show_john" class="box five columns" data-target="#member_john">
                            <div class="avatar avatar-on-hidden">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/john.png">
                                <h4 class="name">John</h4>
                                <p class="position">Creative Director</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="avatar2 avatar-on-hover">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/john.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                     <!-- avatar 5 --->

                        <div id="show_neil" class="box five columns" data-target="#member_neil">
                            <div class="avatar avatar-on-hidden">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/neil.png">
                                <h4 class="name">Neil</h4>
                                <p class="position">Creative Director</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="avatar2 avatar-on-hover">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/neil.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div><!-- container -->

                 <!-- each team member's slide down content -->
                    <div class="member_row">
                        <div class="container">

                     <!-- avatar 1 content --->

                            <div id="member_ryan" class="member-info">
                                <? the_content(); ?>
                            </div><!-- //Ryan -->

                     <!-- avatar 2 content --->

                            <div id="member_brian" class="member-info">
                                <? the_content(); ?>
                            </div>

                     <!-- avatar 3 content --->

                            <div id="member_emma" class="member-info">
                                <? the_content(); ?>
                            </div>

                     <!-- avatar 4 content --->

                            <div id="member_john" class="member-info">
                                <? the_content(); ?>
                            </div>

                     <!-- avatar 5 content --->

                            <div id="member_neil" class="member-info">
                                <? the_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- .container -->
                    </div><!-- .member_row -->

<!-- row 2 -->
                 <!-- Avatars -->
                 <div class="member_block">
                     <div class="container avatars">

                     <!-- avatar 1 --->
                        <div id="show_ryan" class="box five columns" data-target="#member_ryan">
                            <div class="avatar avatar-on-hidden">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/ryan.png">
                                <h4 class="name">Ryan</h4>
                                <p class="position">Creative Director</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="avatar2 avatar-on-hover">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/ryan.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                     <!-- avatar 2 --->

                        <div id="show_brian" class="box five columns" data-target="#member_brian">
                            <div class="avatar avatar-on-hidden">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/brian.png">
                                <h4 class="name">Brian</h4>
                                <p class="position">Director</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="avatar2 avatar-on-hover">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/brian.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                     <!-- avatar 3 --->

                        <div id="show_emma" class="box five columns" data-target="#member_emma">
                            <div class="avatar avatar-on-hidden">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/emma.png">
                                <h4 class="name">Emma</h4>
                                <p class="position">Creative Director</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="avatar2 avatar-on-hover">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/emma.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                     <!-- avatar 4 --->

                        <div id="show_john" class="box five columns" data-target="#member_john">
                            <div class="avatar avatar-on-hidden">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/john.png">
                                <h4 class="name">John</h4>
                                <p class="position">Creative Director</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="avatar2 avatar-on-hover">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/john.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                     <!-- avatar 5 --->

                        <div id="show_neil" class="box five columns" data-target="#member_neil">
                            <div class="avatar avatar-on-hidden">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/neil.png">
                                <h4 class="name">Neil</h4>
                                <p class="position">Creative Director</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="avatar2 avatar-on-hover">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/team/neil.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div><!-- container -->

                 <!-- each team member's slide down content -->
                    <div class="member_row">
                        <div class="container">

                     <!-- avatar 1 content --->

                            <div id="member_ryan" class="member-info">
                                <? the_content(); ?>
                            </div><!-- //Ryan -->

                     <!-- avatar 2 content --->

                            <div id="member_brian" class="member-info">
                                <? the_content(); ?>
                            </div>

                     <!-- avatar 3 content --->

                            <div id="member_emma" class="member-info">
                                <? the_content(); ?>
                            </div>

                     <!-- avatar 4 content --->

                            <div id="member_john" class="member-info">
                                <? the_content(); ?>
                            </div>

                     <!-- avatar 5 content --->

                            <div id="member_neil" class="member-info">
                                <? the_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- .container -->
                    </div><!-- .member_row -->
                </div><!-- .member_block -->
```

Comment: you don't need to do 3 separate loops to get 3 rows.  Before your loop, initialize a counter, like `$x=0;` and then with each iteration you'll increment $x like `$x++;` then you can check if you're on a multiple of 5 with `if($x%5==0)` and inside that if put your html to end/start the next row.  Also, while you're in your loop you can write out your hidden div content, using that counter to give each a unique id, then use javascript to do the hiding/showing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out WP's reference on using [WP_QUERY](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Multiple_Loops) for multiple loops. After looking at your code, your incorrectly querying the WordPress table.

Try this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'team',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
 );

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

if($the_query->have_posts());

while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
<h1 class="entry-title">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</h1>
<div class="content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php 

endwhile;
```

wp_reset_postdata();

You can then dupilcate the loop above, just rename the variables to something like $the_query2.

*EDIT*
- Forgot to add wp_rest_postdata(), what this does is resets the loop and allows you to run a second one.

*Edit 2* - Here is updated code, using this you should be able to modify the code to fit your needs, as i am not going to write your entire page for you. Also make sure your [theme supports thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail).

```
<div class="avatar_block">
    <div class="container">
        <?php
            // Query for Member Info
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'team',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            );

            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($the_query->have_posts())
                ;

            while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
        ?>

            <div id="<?php the_tags(); ?>" class="box five_columns">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <h4 class="name"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>

        <?php
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="member_block">
    <div class="container">
        <?php
            // Query for Member Info
            $args2 = array(
                'post_type' => 'team',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            );

            $the_query2 = new WP_Query($args2);
            if ($the_query2->have_posts())
                ;

            while ($the_query2->have_posts()) : $the_query2->the_post();
        ?>

            <div id="<?php the_tags(); ?>" class="member_info">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>

        <?php
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey this points me in the right direction but doesn't solved how i split the avatars form the slide down content which needs to be in a different container div further down as per my html structure. So the avatar and title will not be in the same while loop. Does that make sense?

Comment: Where are you putting the avatar? Is it part of the custom post type (CPT)? If so then you don't need a separate loop for the avatar. The loop above will pull all content from the CPT, you just have to tell the loop what content you want and wrap it in a div.

Comment: I've added comments into the html structure so you can see what i mean. All the avatars are in one div, with the slide down content that appears for each avatar in a separate DIV below.